# Get all native elements from FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm implementing a Reactive Form in Angular, and I'd like to scroll in the native element if one of form group's control is not valid (but there are a lot of other reasons to access the native element, this is just one of many).

I expected an API like this:

```
for (const key in this.formGroup) {
  const control = this.formGroup[key];
  if (!control.valid) {
    control.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

But, too bad, doesn't exist any property like `FormControl.prototype.nativeElement`.

How can I implement this behaviour, considering that the form is huge and dynamically generated so I can't use `@ViewChild`?

Comment: Something like [fragments](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) ?

Comment: @trichetriche fragments refer to URLs, and by the way isn't possible to retrieve the FormControl ID from its interface

Comment: Fragments are elements identified by their ID that allow Angular to scroll to them when asked to. You just have to use the form control name as the ID to use them.

Comment: But it's a component where I'm not using routing and router-outlets. So it's not appliable

Comment: If you have the router module, it's applicable. If it isn't, then make it applicable by adding the router to your application.

Comment: Applying a whole heavy and complicate module (unused elsewhere) just for a scroll, doesn't it sound as an overkill?

Comment: Look, I'm giving you the answer, if you decide to be stubborn and not use it, then so be it, but as you see, you don't have that many options. Find excuses as much as you want to, you will eventually resort to that. It's the weekend and I'm home now, so I'm done here, good luck with your project and see you around !

Comment: And to answer you, no, it's not a "whole heavy complicate module". Angular use TS so that it can b compiled into small chunks that are tree shaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular JS query to get a reference to the control (combined with the `.ng-invalid` class if necessary):

```
document.querySelector('[formcontrolname="firstName"]')
```

Comment: I ended up with a similar solution. I wanted to answer my own question but you've been faster, thank you!